# create-react-app ошибка

Tags: reactjs

Win 10
Хочу создать REACT app
согласно нативной документации
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app
читаю согласно документации:
.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

.
(модуль create-react-app установлен)
.
запускаю обьявленную команду "npx create-react-app my-app" в терминале
.
получаю ошибку: npx: installed 1 in 4.073s
The "path" argument must be of type string

что должно быть string ? my-app уже и в кавычки брал, все без толку. Какую стринг от меня хотят, подскажите плз ?

Comment: npm -v 5.6.0   установлен

Comment: Попроубуйте `npm install -g npm@5.8.0`
`npm install -g npx@10.0.1`

Comment: Установил, не помогло. То же самое:

Comment: λ npx create-react-app myapp
npx: installed 1 in 4.576s
The "path" argument must be of type string
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\package.json: Unexpected string in JSON at position 520

Answer (score 1):

resolved.
не тот npx вызывался
U must call npx with full path
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx.cmd create-react-app MyApp

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте удалить и заново написать путь
   [image: Попробуйте удалить и заново написать путь]
2. Или попробуйте "npm cache clean" в консоли

Comment: Хмм, я бы как то проще обьяснил, что нужно удалиить, вместо того, чтобы предлагать скрин десктопа со всем тем, что на нём находится.

Comment: @0xdb - впадлу описывать, да и на скрине нет никакой секретной информации